# Active Admin change title of object on Show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

On the Show page, the field *:likes_number* is displayed as "Likes Count Number" however I would like it displayed as "Likes". Following the [documentation](http://activeadmin.info/docs/6-show-pages.html) I tried the below code to change the title but it didn't work. What's the correct way to change the title?

```
  show do 
    attributes_table do
      rows :id, :created_at, :updated_at, :text_content, :embedded_url, :user_id
     row "Likes" do |post|
        post.likes_number
       end 
end
```

http://activeadmin.info/docs/6-show-pages.html

Comment: Try to restart app. Seems like your code is correct.

Comment: Tried restarting, unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: Works like charm for me..